# ListView selectionChanged fired on keyboard navigation

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a n ListView displaying some items, but when i tab to it and navigates with the keyboard (arrow down) it fires the selection-changed event.

Can I prevent this so it only fires selectionChanged on "return/enter"-key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the [ItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick%28v=win.10%29.aspx) handler instead of the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) handler. The ItemClick handler is invoked by a left mouse click or by the enter key.

Comment: Note that you also need to set IsItemClickEnabled to true on the list control.

Comment: i will try this later today

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ListView`'s `IsTabStop` property to false, so it won't come in tab sequence.

Comment: well, i actually want it to be tab-able. My final goal is that the user can navigate the listview with arrow up/down and press enter to select the item. Also mouse navigation/touch should be possible. (Its a  windows8 app)

Comment: Have you tried [ItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick%28v=win.10%29.aspx) event ?